# Subquery not producing expected results (SELECT DISTINCT and COUNT)

Tags: sql, subquery

My query is:

```
SELECT distinct d.Z4BSN2,
  (SELECT COUNT(Z4RMID) 
   FROM ZWE944 as d1 
   where d1.Z4RMID = d.Z4RMID 
    and d1.Z4BSN2 = d.Z4BSN2 )
FROM ZWE944 as d
WHERE Z4RYMD = 170505
```

Source Data:

```
Z4RMID              Z4BSN2      Z4PONO  Z4ITNO      Z4RYMD  Z4RHMS  Z4USER
C17D29014A          801464552   MWV TO  2038284     170505  170103  CNVTST
C87D25211C          801462997   MWV TO  2038292     170505  170103  CNVTST
C87D25273D          801462997   MWV TO  2038292     170505  170103  CNVTST
C87D25281D          801462997   MWV TO  2038292     170505  170103  CNVTST
C87D25282Z          801462997   MWV TO  2038292     170505  170103  CNVTST
```

I'm expecting 2 rows, and the counts of 1 and 5.  However, both rows are giving me a count of 1.  I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question? It might be easier to figure out what is going on if we could see some data and then the final desired result.

Comment: Why do you need to count? You are not using it anywhere

Comment: I am using this query to create a source file for an EDI document.  I need only those two pieces of information.  Added source data for clarification.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well - formatted text here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided what others have said is true (you should add sample data and expected output), you don't seem to need that inner query, you can achieve the same with

```
select  Z4BSN2,
        count(Z4RMID) 
from    ZWE944
where   Z4RYMD = 170505
group by Z4BSN2
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your sample data you are only expecting counts of 1 and 1 because the Z4RMIDs are distinct which means your inner select which has where on Z4RMID will only select one record.

Removing the first where gets what you want e.g:

```
declare @zwe944 table
(
Z4RMID varchar(10),
Z4BSN2 varchar(10),
Z4PONO varchar(10),
Z4ITNO int,
Z4RYMD int,
Z4RHMS int,
Z4User varchar(10) 
)

INSERT INTO @zwe944 VALUES ('C17D29014A',801464552,'MWV TO',2038284,170505,170103,'CNVTST')
INSERT INTO @zwe944 VALUES ('C87D25211C',801462997,'MWV TO',2038292,170505,170103,'CNVTST')
INSERT INTO @zwe944 VALUES ('C87D25273D',801462997,'MWV TO',2038292,170505,170103,'CNVTST')
INSERT INTO @zwe944 VALUES ('C87D25281D',801462997,'MWV TO',2038292,170505,170103,'CNVTST')
INSERT INTO @zwe944 VALUES ('C87D25282Z',801462997,'MWV TO',2038292,170505,170103,'CNVTST')


SELECT distinct d.Z4BSN2,
  (SELECT COUNT(Z4RMID) 
   FROM @ZWE944 as d1 
   where d1.Z4RMID = d.Z4RMID 
    and d1.Z4BSN2 = d.Z4BSN2 )
   FROM @ZWE944 as d
    WHERE Z4RYMD = 170505

SELECT distinct d.Z4BSN2,
  (SELECT COUNT(Z4RMID) 
   FROM @ZWE944 as d1 
   where d1.Z4BSN2 = d.Z4BSN2 )
FROM @ZWE944 as d
WHERE Z4RYMD = 170505
```

The second query gives counts of 1 and 4 but that is right given the data.